# CSS layout on HTML5

Tags: css, html, layout, html5-canvas

I am developing one web application in HTML5 and js. And I am using some '**Canvas**' tags in it. So I would like to structure them on the screen like:
[image]

I have achieved it by using such CSS tags as: *margin-right, margin-left, top, position*.
The problem is when I use these css tags, then I am more or less adapting the whole layout to one screen only, unfortunately my aim is to support any screen possible.

Maybe there are professionals in layouting who could help with this particular problem.

P.S. When window size is changed, canvases should not be resized

Comment: You need to be more specific: what happens when the screen size changes? For instance, should the canvases on the left and right get smaller? Should the middle one get smaller? Both? Neither? Should they decrease proportionally?

Comment: no, nothing should happen when the window sizes change, srry, forgot to specify

Comment: I believe I have provided a solution to what you are looking for

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what i have asked for, before i knew about the previously proposed solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created you a demo.

I believe [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dU2A4/) is what you want.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="col1">
        <div class="canvas">Canvas-Left-1
            <div class="innercanvas">Canvas-Left-1-1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="canvas">Canvas-Left-2
            <div class="innercanvas">Canvas-Left-2-1</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="col2">Canvas 0</div>

    <div id="col3">
        <div class="canvas">Canvas-Rigt-1
            <div class="innercanvas">Canvas-Right-1-1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="canvas">Canvas-Right-2
            <div class="innercanvas">Canvas-Right-1-1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#wrapper {display: block; margin: 0 auto; width: 1000px; background-color: green; overflow: auto;}
#col1 {display: inline-block; width:200px; background-color: gray; position: relative; float: left;}
#col2 {display: inline-block; width:600px; background-color: yellow; position: relative; float: left;}
#col3 {display: inline-block; width:200px; background-color: blue; position: relative; float: left;}
.canvas {background-color: black; margin: 10px; color: white}
.innercanvas {background-color: purple; margin: 10px; color: white}​
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe its a good idea to use a css framework like twitter [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/).

Its build up for different screen sizes and crossbrowser. It also offers a [responsive design](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive).

Have a look at the [gridsystem](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html).

About one canvas inside another:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span4">..</div>
      <div class="span4">..  </div>
      <div class="span4">..</div>
    </div>
  <div class="span8">...</div>
</div>
```

You can do "unlimited" nesting of columns, see 'Nesting columns' in documentation linked above.

Comment: looks nice, but I would like to go with the less robust and easy solution

Comment: Boris using a gridsystem is probably the "easiest" solution. You would need to understand CSS a little more to be able to implement it yourself, aside from dealing with possible hacks on the way.

Comment: I am dealing now with both of your proposals, it seems to be quite easy as from the example, but I am not very much sure that I need all of the files from any of your proposed projects.. It is basically what I need, but in a very very expanded way

Comment: But there is still one question unanswered, how I should put one canvas inside another, because if I use both of your proposals, I will need to use "moving" function, like padding or margin, in order to adjust one layer inside another

Comment: thank you for your proposal which will expand my knowledge :)

Answer (score 0):

Boris you would need to either implement it using outside containers for each area (ie. 3 outer-divs, one for each column, and one "main" div to position to in the middle of the screen, using percentages and max/min width to control the desired output).

Or save yourself some trouble and use a fluid grid system like those:

- http://cssgrid.net/
- http://www.designinfluences.com/fluid960gs/

You may want to take a look [here](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluidgrids/) too, there is some neat information on fluid layouts.

Comment: thank you for your proposal which will expand my knowledge :)